# Unable to execute a Java IF-ELSE program in HackerRank

Tags: java, if-statement

I am solving an **IF-ELSE** program using **JAVA** in **HackerRank**, it executes just fine when I give custom inputs from the console ( i.e 3 and 24 ). But when I try to submit it again, it fails all 8 test cases.

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-if-else/problem

*The code*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = sc.nextInt();
if(n%2==0 || n>=2 || n<=5 || n>=0)
        System.out.println("wierd");
    else
        System.out.println("not wierd");
if(n%2==0 && n>=6 && n<=20 && n>20)
        System.out.println("wierd");
    else
        System.out.println("not wierd");
sc.close();
    }
}
```

*UPDATED CODE:*

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

int n = sc.nextInt();
if(n%2==0 && n>2 && n<5 || n%2==0 && n>6 && n<20 || n%2==0 && n>20 && n<=100)
    System.out.println("not wierd");
else
    System.out.println("wierd");
sc.close();
    }
}
```

*output:*

Wierd

Not Wierd

*How to correct my code?*

Comment: `n<=20 && n>20` - this doesn't work. Also, why are there two different if-else statements? You are only supposed to evaluate the input once right?

Comment: Don't try to combine the conditions in the first instance. Write one condition for each bullet.

Comment: Have a look at the requirements again and evaluate them one by one if this makes it easier for you. _Weird:_ once _n_ is odd OR if it is even and between 6 and 20. _Not weird:_ Even and between 2 and 5 OR even and greater than 20. Your current code does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're using or instead of and in the first if-statement.

The statement n%2==0 || n>=2 is going to catch every integer greater than 1, regardless of whether it's an even or odd number.